# iOS custom gesture + sidebar

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'd like to implement a sidebar that is revealed/hidden with a custom gesture.

Sidebar - A small window that appears either on the left or right. It shouldn't be huge, but big enough to encompass a few buttons and maybe some text.

Custom Gesture - I want a swipe to reveal/hide the sidebar very similar to what is done with the notification center in iOS 5. With the notification center, you place your finger at the top and swipe down. I'd like a similar gesture. So if the user has his/her finger to the left of the screen and swipes his/her finger onto the screen, then reveal the sidebar on the left. To hide it, just do the reverse gesture. Ditto for showing the sidebar on the right.